# jquery onsubmit return false not working

Tags: jquery

Im trying to verify prevent index.php form from redirecting to login.php using onsubmit return false on script.js. script.js file gets ajax response from login.php. But the onsubmit return false is not working. here are the codes

index php file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myForm"   action="login.php" method="POST">
Username:<input type="text"  id="username" name="username"><br  />

Password:<input type="password"  id="password" name="password"><br  />
<button id="submit">Login</button>

</form>
<div id="ack"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

login php file

```
<?php 
include("dbcon.php");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["password"]));

$sql = "select count(*) from users WHERE username='$username' 
AND password='$password '";
$res= mysql_query($sql);
$row =  mysql_fetch_array($res);

if( $row[0] >0 )
echo "login successful";
else
echo "login failed";
?>
```

script js file

```
$("button#submit").click( function(){
    if( $("#username").val()=="" || $("#password").val()=="")

    $("div#ack").html("Please enter username and password");
    else
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),//attribute eg login.php
    $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),//break data into key value pairs
               function(data){//catch daat from login.php eg login failed or login                                      
                $("div#ack").html(data);    
    });

    $("#myForm").submit( function(){
        });
return false;

    });
```

Assistance of any kind will be appreciated

Comment: Any console errors ?

Comment: Do you wrap your code in document ready handler? BTW, you aren't returning false from submit handler (nested in click handler) but from click event of button. But as click event of default submit button is fired on form submit, it wouldn't be the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *preventDefault* function in the click event.

```
$("button#submit").click( function(event){
if( $("#username").val()=="" || $("#password").val()=="")

$("div#ack").html("Please enter username and password");
else
$.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),//attribute eg login.php
$("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),//break data into key value pairs
           function(data){//catch daat from login.php eg login failed or login                                      
            $("div#ack").html(data);    
});
event.preventDefault();
return false; 
});
```

Comment: Some description of what the issue is and what you changed is always welcome.

Comment: I have tried this code `$("#myForm").submit( function(e){e.preventDefault(); if( $("#username").val()=="" || ("#password").val()==""){ 
 $("div#ack").html("Please enter username and password");}
 else {        $.post(this.action, $(this).find(':input').serializeArray(), function(data) {        
            $("div#ack").html(data);      });    } });` . It is still submiting to login page, no error in php or jquery.      I have also tried modifyingmy code by adding `.click(function(event)` and then calling `event.preventDefault();` before `return false;` simply no improvement at the moment

Comment: Hmm Somethings is not right... try this code. $("#myForm").on('submit', function(e){
           
        if ( $("#username").val()=="" || ("#password").val()=="") {   
            $("div#ack").html("Please enter username and password");
        } else { 
            $.post(
                this.action, 
                $(this).find(':input').serializeArray(), 
                function(data) { 
                    $("div#ack").html(data); 
                }); 
        } 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you require you need to hook to the `submit` event of the `form` element and stop that instead by using `event.preventDefault()`. Try this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "") {
        $("div#ack").html("Please enter username and password");
    }
    else {
        $.post(this.action, $(this).find(':input').serializeArray(), function(data) {           
            $("div#ack").html(data);    
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: There are no errors, the index.php is behaving like jquery is not there

Comment: You're right. When the code is formatted correctly the braces do match. However the solution is the same.